# Comparing Differences in 2 Columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to compare 2 columns, `ID` and `add`. Using ID as the key,  if the corresponding `add` are different, `diff` should show "Yes."

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1234", "1234", "7491", "7319", "321", "321"), add = c("ABC", "DEF", "HIJ", "KLM", "WXY", "WXY"))
```

**Expected Output**

```
    ID add diff
1 1234 ABC  Yes
2 1234 DEF  Yes
3 7491 HIJ   No
4 7319 KLM   No
5  321 WXY   No
6  321 WXY   No
```

Comment: Yep it will be a 'No'. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have also a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(diff = ifelse(length(unique(add))>1, "YES", "NO")) # n_distict(add)>1 will also work 
  #mutate(diff = ifelse(n_distinct(add)>1, "YES", "NO"))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   ID [4]
# ID    add   diff 
# <fct> <fct> <chr>
# 1 1234  ABC   YES  
# 2 1234  DEF   YES  
# 3 7491  HIJ   NO   
# 4 7319  KLM   NO   
# 5 321   WXY   NO   
# 6 321   WXY   NO
```

Comment: isn't `n_distinct()`  a thing? (which can replace `length(unique())`?

Comment: So many functions to remember, apparently it's not a thing in my head.. thanks

Comment: Do you really need `ifelse`? Wouldn't be just `if` enough?

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[, diff := if (uniqueN(add) > 1) "Yes" else "No", by = ID]
df

     ID add diff
1: 1234 ABC  Yes
2: 1234 DEF  Yes
3: 7491 HIJ   No
4: 7319 KLM   No
5:  321 WXY   No
6:  321 WXY   No
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach would be:

```
df$diff <- sapply(df$ID, function(x) {
  s <- df$add[df$ID == x]
  length(s) != 1 & length(unique(s)) != 1
})

> df
    ID add  diff
1 1234 ABC  TRUE
2 1234 DEF  TRUE
3 7491 HIJ FALSE
4 7319 KLM FALSE
5  321 WXY FALSE
6  321 WXY FALSE
```

If you're depending on Yes-No do, `ifelse(df$diff, "Yes", "No")`.

Or – as *@sindri_baldur* suggested – do this, which is faster:

```
unlist(sapply(unique(df$ID), function(x) {
  rows <- df$ID == x
  s <- df$add[rows]
  rep(length(s) != 1 & length(unique(s)) != 1, sum(rows)) 
}))
```

Comment: It would seem enough to loop over `unique(df$ID)`... something like `unlist(sapply(unique(df$ID), function(x) {rows <- (df$ID == x); s <- df$add[rows]; rep(length(s) != 1 & length(unique(s)) != 1, sum(rows)) }))` would work.

Comment: Yes. Output is correct but might be inefficient if there are many obs per ID.